# Lightning-modal custom event not working in winter 23 release

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

I was exploring new lightning-modal module in winter23 release but seems like custom event of the modal is not working. here's my code. I believe lightning-modal is already GA but struggling to understand why the custom event is not working.

modalHelperCode

```
import { api } from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {
    @api content;

    handleOkay() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('select', {
            detail: {
              id: 42
            }
          }));
        this.close('okay');
    }
}
```

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body> Content: {content} </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="OK" onclick={handleOkay}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

modalButton

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import MyModal from 'c/myModal';

export default class modalButton extends LightningElement {
    handleSelectEvent(detail) {
        const { id, value } = detail;
        console.log(`select event fired elem with id ${id} and value: ${value}`);
      }
      
      handleOpenModal() {
        MyModal.open({
          label: 'Modal Title',
          size: 'large',
          description: 'Modal Title with brief description',
          onselect: (e) => {
            //e.stopPropagation();
            this.handleSelectEvent(e.detail);
          }
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log('result>>',result);
            
        });
      }
}
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-button
        onclick={handleOpenModal}
        aria-haspopup="modal"
        label="Open My Modal">
    </lightning-button> 
    <p>Result: {result}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you add in your HTML?

Comment: Yes added the HTML as well @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Please add in your imports too and whole Javascript code?

Comment: Hi
Can you please go through some basics on Custom Events? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events_create_dispatch

Comment: Added the whole JS as well. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: @Soumi What do you see in the console.log ..

Comment: When i click on 'X' on modal it's coming as undefined as mentioned in the document as well , but when i click on Ok button the close() method is not being called, It gets stuck in the eventDispatch line.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of console.log() and what is your instance. Also can you add exact names of your files too.

Comment: https://imgur.com/E7JvZlA Checked with chrome debugger as well , when i click on OK button handleOkay() method gets called and completes the transaction on dispatchevent but Close() method of Modal doesn't run and Open() method promises never gets resolved in this case.  
Tried in two instances got the same issue : AP16, CS24.
modalButton (callerComponent)
myModal(modalHelper)

Comment: Your code works fine for me in latest chrome browser! So I think raise a support case to see if there is anything else.

Comment: Sure @MohithShrivastava will probably raise a case to understand the issue, meanwhile i believe i can pass the same data in the close() method of the modal as well, so probably i'll use this as a workaround till i get any response from support team.

Comment: Same issue, when trying to dispatch custom event from class extending LightningModal. The error is only visible when wrapping the dispatch in try/catch.
```
error TypeError: EventTarget.dispatchEvent: Argument 1 does not implement interface Event. dispatchEvent aura_prod.js:6452 dispatchEvent aura_prod.js:3815 ``` ```
import {api} from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal'; export default class Modal extends LightningModal { // .... unrelated code handleAction(event) { try { this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('select', { detail: { id: 'Foo' } })); } catch(e) { //Winter 23 has bro

Answer (score 8):

This works only if you have the [Lightning Web Security Enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) in the org.

If that setting is disabled, it fails with an error below

> error TypeError: EventTarget.dispatchEvent: Argument 1 does not implement interface Event.
> dispatchEvent aura_prod.js:6452
> dispatchEvent aura_prod.js:3815

I am raising this internally at Salesforce to log it as a bug.

**UPDATE**

This is logged as a bug and will be fixed at some point. We recommend that if you can enable the Lightning Web Security setting, you should.

There is a workaround for this as of today if you have Lightning Web Security disabled.

Wrap around the code that dispatches the event from the Modal within a Child Component so a custom Event is dispatched instead of standard event.

Let's create a child component for the `lightning-button` used as the footer in the modal component, as shown below.

**buttonWrapper.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-button
    label="Ok"
    onclick={handleOkay}
></lightning-button>
```

**buttonWrapper.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class ButtonWrapper extends LightningElement {
    handleOkay() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("select", {
            bubbles: true, 
            composed: true,
            detail: {
                id: 42
            }
        })
    );
}
```

}

Modify the modal component code to use the Wrapper child component

```
<template>
<lightning-modal-header label="My Modal Heading"></lightning-modal-header>
<lightning-modal-body> Content: {content} </lightning-modal-body>
<lightning-modal-footer>
    <c-button-wrapper></c-button-wrapper>
</lightning-modal-footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for raising it internally. I got this same error today and thought I was losing my mind for some time.

Comment: Is there a known issue for this or a plan to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I've observed this happening even with LWS enabled in an org.

What worked for me to fix this was making the function that dispatches the event asynchronous

```
    async publishEvent(){
        await this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('event'));
    }
```