# this.close() will not close Lightning Modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

I am following the documentation from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation):

> **Close a Modal Instance**
>
> Use this.close(result) to close the modal, where result is anything
> you want to return from the modal. The .close() operation is
> asynchronous to display a brief fade out animation before the modal is
> destroyed. The result data can’t be modified after the close operation
> begins.
>
> You can also close the modal with the default close button, the X at
> the top right corner. Closing a modal like this is the same as calling
> this.close() with an undefined result, so any data input is lost.

`this.close()` does nothing for me.

My HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header>Test Modal Header</lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>Test Modal Body</lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={closeModal} class="slds-var-p-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

My JS:

```
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class TestModal extends LightningModal {

    closeModal() {
        console.log('close modal');
        this.close();
    }

}
```

I can see the log in the console but the modal does not close.

**edit**
If it matters, I am triggering the LWC that contains the modal from a Quick Action.

**edit2** attaching a screenshot of the quick action.

[image]

Comment: The code used to trigger the modal would be helpful, since you are doing this from a quick action.

Comment: @sfdcfox - done

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that the modal is part of a quick action. So the solution is to close the screen quick action. Following the documentation from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-screen.html):

> **Open and Close the Modal Window**
>
> A screen quick action opens a Lightning web component in a modal
> window. To close the modal window programmatically, for example, to
> create a Cancel button, build UI that dispatches the custom event
> CloseActionScreenEvent. Import the event from the lightning/actions
> module.

First the component will need to import "CloseActionScreenEvent".

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";
```

Then it can dispatch a "CloseActionScreenEvent" which will then close the quick action screen and the modal.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
```

**UPDATE**
Because of a known [bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387924/lightning-modal-custom-event-not-working-in-winter-23-release) the solution(if your Lightning Web Security cannot be enabled) requires for the implementation of a child component that will then fire this event. Do not forget to enable to bubble up like so:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({bubbles: true, composed: true}));
```